# Set an argument of a function as the name of a global variable defined within a function in R

Tags: r, function, global-variables, assign, variable-names

I would like to set a functions argument as the variable name of a global variable defined within a function.
The reason is to create a general function which, connects to a database downloads data into a global variable with the argument of the function as its name.

This would allow to connect to a database once, download data, store them in a variable with a defined name and use it outside of the function. (Alternatively I am also open for different approaches)

```
test=function(name_argument){
substitute(name_argument)<<-2
}
test("name")
name->2 | The global variable should be callable with the variable name
```

I have tried using `assign(), substitute(), eval()` in various forms, without any success.

Does anyone a) know a solution to this and b) can describe the logic behind it. (For example why does substitute seemingly not work with global variables)

Comment: If you really feel like you need to do that, use `assign`. Just be aware, that it is bad practice and you almost certainly don't actually need it.

Comment: There is also the `<<-` operator.

Comment: @JDL They attempted to use `<<-` in the question.

Comment: they also attempted `assign` :)